# LG5 call interrupted with cheek touching "hold"

Tags: calls, lg

LG G5 accidentally touching "Hold" button with cheek during phone calls, thereby unintentionally put the call on "hold".

How to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Most Dialer apps use the proximity sensor to turn off the screen while it's on call to prevent accidental touch. So, either 1) the Dialer app you're using doesn't support this, or 2) the proximity sensor is not working properly. Try installing 3rd-party Dialer app or sensor checking app.